# How can I play Battlefield 3 in Freeplay mode, like in BF1942?

Tags: battlefield-3

I want to play Battlefield 3 in Freeplay mode, like in BF1942, but I was unable to find a way to do it.

How can I play Battlefield 3 in Freeplay mode?

Answer (score 1):

You can't. The functionality just does not exist unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a freeplay mode in Battlefield 3.